# Script prints args before executing and waits for me to press [enter] before terminating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following scraper draft:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import sys

requestedURL = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(requestedURL)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

passage = ''
for tr in tree.cssselect("div [class='passage-content passage-class-0']"):
    for each in tr:
        for e in each:
            for x in e:
                if x.text_content() == 'Footnotes:' or x.text_content() == 'Cross references:': 
                    passage += '\n'
                    passage = passage.lstrip('\n')
                    sys.stdout.write(passage)
                    sys.exit(0)
                if not x.text_content()[0].isdigit():
                    passage += '\n\n'+x.text_content()+'\n\n'
                else:
                    passage += x.text_content()
            passage = passage.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
```

When I run this, I do get the output I want, but I also get two undesired events:

- The arguments are printed
- The script doesn't actually end until I press `Enter`

Example:

```
python bg_scrape.py https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A1&version=ESV
[1] 48648

John 3:1

New International Version (NIV)

Jesus Teaches Nicodemus

3 Now there was a Pharisee, a man named Nicodemus who was a member of the Jewish ruling council.

// this line doesn't show up until I hit enter
[1]+  Done  python bg_scrape.py https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A1
```

Worth noting that this only started happening once I put `requestedURL` as a `sys.arg` instead of a static string in the code.

Comment: What is the output of running `which python` on your command line?

Comment: Oh, it might be the "&" in the cmd line parameter. Try putting the param in double quotes `python bg_scrape.py "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A1&version=ESV"`

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this at all? I guess it's a shell thing, not a python thing, so likely not? =/

Comment: Yep it's a shell thing, sot he only way to avoid it is to quote the param, or backslash-escape the chars the shell will intercept/interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the "&" in the cmd line parameter. Try putting the param in double quotes `python bg_scrape.py "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A1&version=ESV"`

Essentially what's happening is your shell is actually running two things:

- `python bg_scrape.py https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A1` as a backgrounded process
- then running `version=ESV` which assigns a shell variable

when you press enter, the shell is just giving you an update on any backgrounded processes that have finished (in this case, the one you just started).